# "Failed on converting date string to date number" due to mixed of timestamp format

Tags: string, matlab, date

Somehow the timestamp of my raw data is,

```
A= 
{'12/5/2015 11:59:58 PM';
'13/5/2015'; % ideally this is '13/5/2015 12:00 AM'
'13/5/2015 12:00:01 AM;
'13/5/2015 12:00:01 AM}
```

I could not perform datenum due to the **mixed** of timestamp format where,

`datenum(A,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS PM')` gave me "Failed on converting date string to date number"

How do i go about converting all entities in A (which has **MIXED** timeformat) to time number series?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert mm/dd/yyyy to a form usable for datenum MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126185/convert-mm-dd-yyyy-to-a-form-usable-for-datenum-matlab)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a huge sample set with different time format,  which require either the format of 'dd/mm/yyy HH:MM:SS PM' or 'dd/mm/yyyy'. But I do not know which index requires which format, how to I convert them into time series as a whole with mixed format?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the indices of the ones that use a particular format, you can use regular expressions.
Take for example the longer format and match it to your `A`:

```
longformat = '^\d\d/(1?)\d/\d\d\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M$';
found = regexp(A,longformat) 
ans = 

    [1]
    []
    [1]
    [1]
```

So, you can then use something like an anonymous function to find which of the answers were found:

```
foundlong = @(A,expr) cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x),regexp(A,expr));
found = foundlong(A,longformat)
found =

     1
     0
     1
     1
```

Now you have indices where you can use `datenum()` with the specific format.
For example:

```
d(found) = datenum(A{found},'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM');
```

***CAUTION:*** If you start with the shorter expression, say

```
shortformat = '^\d\d/(1?)\d/\d\d\d\d';
```

you'll match **all** of them.  So, make sure that you add in the end of sequence `$`, to match the end of the string:

```
shortformat = '^\d\d/(1?)\d/\d\d\d\d$';
```